# json.loads fails with "ValueError: Extra data:" but works with dummy data

Tags: python, json

I am having an issue with json.loads(). When i try to decode a json string I get an error. But if I test it with a similar dummy string, it works. What can be the problem here?

Code:

```
dummy_test = """{"state":{"reported": "hum":33.1,"temp":22.3,"relay":false,"pir":10964},"desired":{"hum":33.1,"temp":22.3,"pir":10964}}}"""

def sensor_update(client, userdata, message):
    print("++++++++update++++++++++")

    print("###" + dummy_test + "###")
    print(type(dummy_test))
    sensor_bath = json.loads(dummy_test)

    print("###" + message.payload + "###")
    print(type(message.payload))
    sensor_bath = json.loads(message.payload)

    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n")
```

Output:

```
++++++++update++++++++++
###{"state":{"reported":{"hum":33.1,"temp":22.3,"relay":false,"pir":10964},"desired":{"hum":33.1,"temp":22.3,"pir":10964}}}###
<type 'str'>
###{"state":{"reported":{"hum":33.2,"temp":22.3,"relay":false,"pir":10964},"desired":{"hum":33.2,"temp":22.3,"pir":10964}}}###
<type 'str'>
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/internal/workers.py", line 147, in _dispatch
    self._dispatch_one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/internal/workers.py", line 154, in _dispatch_one
    self._dispatch_methods[event_type](mid, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/internal/workers.py", line 237, in _dispatch_message
    message_callback(None, None, message)  # message_callback(client, userdata, message)
  File "sensord.py", line 43, in sensor_update
    sensor_bath = json.loads(message.payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 121 - line 1 column 122 (char 120 - 121)
```

The first json.loads succeeds, but the second one fails.

Comment: ``"reported": "hum":33.1,`` is not valid json.

Comment: Did you forget a "{" when copying the data?

Answer (score 1):

The second example - the one supposed to raise the exception - works fine here, so there's something more (that you didn't post) in your failing `message.payload`.

Actually the error message complains about "extra data" at positions 121-122 while the printed string is only 120 characters long, so you very certainly have some trailing non-printable (or not printed by your console / terminal / IDE / whatever) characters at the end of `message.payload`. You can check this out by printing the inner representation of the string instead of it's human-readable version:

```
print("### '" + repr(message.payload) + "' ###")
```

Once you find out what those gremlins are, you can get rid of them using `str.strip()` with the appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why my question got down voted, but I found the problem. My payload string had a trailing '\0'